# How do I encourage ChatGPT to speak more like me?

Tags: chatgpt, prompt-design

Providing an email I drafted, I asked ChatGPT to rewrite it to be more concise, while also asking the style of language to remain similar to the original. ChatGPT sometimes does okay with this request, but often will still default to a very formal or stilted speaking style. Then, if I ask ChatGPT to be more casual, it will often sound very unnatural, often overusing idioms.

I once did the rewrite myself, and prompted ChatGPT to tell me how I could've asked for it to produce something with language similar to this. The generated reply was pretty much a rewording of 'try to keep the language casual' that didn't really produce anything different from what I am troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to self-describe "your" style, let the LLM you are using (eg: ChatGTP) describe it!

1. Feed your text to ChatGPT and ask it to describe the style.
2. Then, - start a new chat and use that description as a prompt. Check results.
3. Tweak and repeat steps 1 & 2 until GPT gives you satisfactory results.
4. (optional) If you then want GPT to always use this style, you can put it into Custom Instructions.

---

See it in action: https://chat.openai.com/share/b006728b-903f-46b0-89f6-df845a95b21e

1. User: **Naive prompt** (notice, that i am using a browsing plugin - WebPilot, to avoid the need to copy-paste article itself, piece by piece.):

```
Read the article at https://{TYPE URL OF THE ACTUAL TEXT}

Then describe the writing style of that article in a way that could be used to instruct an LLM, like ChatGPT, so i can apply author's style to more texts. Up to 150 words.
```

2. GPT: **Summary**:

```
The writing style of the article "__NAME__" [...] is characterized by a direct, instructional tone. It's designed as a step-by-step guide, providing detailed strategies for playing [...] in the game [...]. The author uses concise sentences, bullet points, and numbered lists to organize the content, making it easy to follow. Casual language and conversational phrases are employed to engage the reader, and the author occasionally addresses the reader directly with words like "you" and "your." There's a blend of technical game terminology and everyday language, reflecting a balance between expertise and accessibility. To instruct an LLM like ChatGPT to emulate this style, the focus should be on clear, direct communication, organized presentation, and a blend of technical knowledge with a conversational tone.
```

3. User: **Follow-up prompt**:

```
Please write a system prompt that would instruct ChatGPT to emulate this style.
```

4. GPT: **Instruction**:

```
Certainly! Here's a system prompt that would instruct ChatGPT to emulate the writing style found in "c69’s Guide to Offensive Gauls":

You are to write in the style of a direct, instructional guide, similar to a step-by-step tutorial for playing a strategy game. Use concise sentences, bullet points, and numbered lists to organize the content. Blend technical game terminology with everyday language, maintaining a balance between expertise and accessibility. Engage the reader with a conversational tone, occasionally addressing them directly with words like "you" and "your." Focus on clear, direct communication, and present the information in an organized and easy-to-follow manner.
```

Comment: obviously, if you want to emulate the emails, you might need (way) more than one example for GPT to figure out your style - since the emails are usually quite short.

Comment: This is a great description of what I alluded to I am already doing, sadly this isn't quite consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide examples to ChatGPT. If you use the Website, use your prompt to give examples, like:

> Follow the same style of the examples to rewrite the final input: Example 1: [your example]. Example 2: [your example]. Final input: [request]

If you use the Playground or the API this is easier to do, since you can change the role or create more complex prompts.

Comment: When I provide examples, it leans way too close to the content in the examples.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using one-shot or few-shot prompting. This means including one or more examples of input/output pairs with your request. For example, if I wanted it to concisely answer simple arithmetic problems, I might use a prompt such as:

```
You solve simple arithmetic problems, answering with only the numerical value.

Question: What is 7 - 2?
Answer: 5

Question: what is 8 plus 3
Answer: 11

Question: What is 5 + 1?
Answer:
```